# Kotlin type mistmatch () -> SomeType vs SomeType

Tags: kotlin

I am working thru the Kotlin Koans and ran into this type mismatch.  I know there are other solutions to the problem, but I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

The basic problem seems to be that I am generating a set of `Product`s via a `flatMap`

```
val allOrderedProducts = customers.flatMap {it.orders.flatMap {it.products}}.toSet()
```

then I use this as the receiver for a fold

```
allOrderedProducts.fold(products) { theList, theProduct -> { ... } }
```

the inferred type for `theProduct` is `() -> Product` rather than `Product`

Here is the actual function that I get the type mismatch on (it's not *done*, rather just syntax correct enough to show the type mismatch)

Can someone explain why this does not work?

```
// Return the set of products that were ordered by every customer
fun Shop.getSetOfProductsOrderedByEveryCustomer(): Set<Product> {
    val products: Set<Product> = setOf()
    val allOrderedProducts = customers.flatMap {it.orders.flatMap {it.products}}.toSet()
    allOrderedProducts.fold(products) { theList, theProduct -> 
        customers.all { customer ->
            val orderedProducts = customer.orders.flatMap { it.products }           
            orderedProducts.contains { theProduct }  // type mismatch inferred type is () -> Product but Product was expected 
        }
        val ret: Set<Product> = setOf()
        ret
    }
    val retValue: Set<Product> = setOf()
    return retValue
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer I'm not a Kotlin expert at all)

This seems to be a simple syntax error; this line:

```
 orderedProducts.contains { theProduct }
```

should probably be

```
 orderedProducts.contains(theProduct)
```

(replace the curly braces with "normal" braces)